# android application - android emulator virtual sd card - swf file not loading

Tags: java, android, virtual, android-sdcard

I want to display an swf file in my android application.

For testing purposes am using android emulator . So i created a virtual sd card for the application to read the files.Inside this sd card i put my swf file and am trying to open the swf file in my code.

Am not getting any error on log cat, but getting a blank screen .

Following my code displaying swf on WebView.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.loadswf);
            String html =
                "<object width=\"550\" height=\"400\"><param name=\"movie\" value=\"file:///Demo_mobile.swf\">" +
                "<embed src=\"file:///Demo_mobile.swf\" width=\"550\" height=\"400\"> </embed> </object>";
                String mimeType = "text/html";
                String encoding = "utf-8";
            WebView wv=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
            wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            wv.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
            wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("null", html, mimeType, encoding, "");
            wv.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());

    }
```

Experts please give me a solution for this issue.??

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, that may helpful to you!

```
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
```

You can then load data into the webview like so

```
    String html = "<object width=\"550\" height=\"400\"> <param name=\"movie\" value=\"file:///sdcard/flash/2204355.swf\"> <embed src=\"file:///sdcard/flash/2204355.swf\" width=\"550\" height=\"400\"> </embed> </object>";
    String mimeType = "text/html";
    String encoding = "utf-8";

    mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("null", html, mimeType, encoding, "");
```

I simply made custom html inside the program and told it to load a flash file that I had stored in the flash folder on my sdcard.

Comment: what was the difference the code in my question and the code that you had given..?? :)

Comment: I had applied here my working code, so i can found difference in path hereby.

Comment: path ..?in your case you put the file in location sdcard/flash and in my case i had put the file directly under sdcard.?? so i need to put like this only..right? is there any way to see the virtual sd card contents on android emulator.?